# Cannot specify -c with multiple files

Tags: c, file, gcc, makefile

I've got this problem with my `makefile`:

```
gcc -c src/uno.c src/uno.h -o src/uno.o
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

How can i create a `.o` file with multiple files?

Comment: Do you want them really as one .o, or as one archive, .a, or just to link them all to achieve a final executable built from multiple .c files?

Comment: The `-c` is not needed when doing one pass compilation/linking, use `-o` only here. Also by convention headers (`.h`) are included by a module (`.c`) file. And therefore are **not passed to the compiler** directly.

Comment: Anyway, seeing the relevant portion of the `makefile` would help.

Comment: i need e couple of .o and after link them all... but i need the #include like the MvG's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The header files (`src/uno.h` in this case) are referenced from within the files, and should not be named again on the command line:

```
gcc -c src/uno.c -o src/uno.o
```

You *might* have to name the directory where to find them, using the `-I` flag. But if you `#include "uno.h"` in your sources, then gcc will find the file already, as it searches for it in the same directory which also contains `uno.c`.

You can compile multiple fils and link them into a single binary, e.g.

```
gcc -o myApp myAppMain.c myAppUtil.c myAppStuff.c
```

But that means you'll have to recompile everything if a single source changes, as the intermediate objects are not kept. If you work with object files, there is always one compiler invocation per translation unit.

There is a feature to precompile headers, but in that case, you'd *only* compile the header, not the `uno.c` file. And in any case, this is pretty advanced, so you probably won't need it.

Comment: approved, this is the answer! :D ty